# Put works in Postman but not AXIOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, mern

This is the weirdest thing in my MERN app. When I do a PUT from Postman to my api it works and updates my api and mongoDB. On the front-end it doesn't update the api even though console logs are showing the correct values and the url is the same? Any help or direction would be appreciated... been playing with it for days now.

POSTMAN PROOF UPDATES WORK

[image]
[image]

The code for my axios is as follows:

```
handlePlayerSubmit(id, player) {
    console.log('This is the id: ' + id);
    console.log('This is the player: ' + player);

    let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/api/teams';
    //sends the id and new author/text to our api
    axios.put(`${apiUrl}/${id}`, player).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

}

So I know it's firing due to the console logs... not sure why its not updating the api?

Also it's not console.logging an error.

NETWORK SCREEN SHOT IN DEV TOOLS

[image]

HEADERS FROM NETWORK TAB:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you check the request format in the Network tab and confirm it is correct?

Comment: Are you setting the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: I am in postman

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I added  a pic of the network screen shot

Comment: @angelHack Can you click on one of those and paste the request headers being passed?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings thanks. just added the screen shots. Appreciate the help with this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because Axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To serialize in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format you will need to use one of the [techniques described in the Axios documentation](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format).

I think [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) is a nice solution for you:

```
let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/api/teams';
//sends the id and new author/text to our api
axios.put(`${apiUrl}/${id}`, qs.stringify(player)).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Added a screen shot of network in devtools still nothing with that qs

Comment: Determine why your server is returning a 304. Compare every header value in postman to the headers in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Axios doesn't like posting plain objects.

One way to workaround issue is with `FormData`:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('param1', 'hi');
formData.append('param2', 'hello');

axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/some-endpoint/',
    data: formData
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1195