# Get request is not working with axios but working with postman

Tags: javascript, axios, get, postman

I've made a MongoDB `GET` request route named **users/auth** to create authentication by searching for the records provided in the request's body, inside the database. When I send the request via **POSTMAN** then it gives the expected response (eg: "true")
[image]

But when I tried to send the same request inside my react-app with **AXIOS** it gives an unexpected response(eg: false) with `status code: ok`. I'm not sure of what wrong I'm doing.

```js
//some valid objects which should return true
//but it return's false
users = {
"email": 'abc@gm.com',
"password": 'abcdef'
}

axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/auth', users)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
  //expected: true
  // actual result: false
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848099/put-works-in-postman-but-not-axios) problem but It didn't fixed my problem.

Comment: You're sending a get request in postman with a body? Usually the parameters are added to the URL for GET requests What happens if you add the values to the `Params` tab in postman instead and remove the body?

Comment: it return false(unexpected) :( Am I doing wrong in sending AXIOS request?

Comment: Are you sure it should be a GET request? If it works with a body then try changing to POST in axios and postman (and put the params in the body). The other possibility is a bug server side. How do you know the server is responding correctly?

Comment: Because I've tested the endpoints with postman it's working fine. I want GET, hence POST will not work :(

Comment: Can you check what value email and password are received on the server?